# REST API how to restrict access

Tags: rest

I am learning REST APIs and suppose we have a URL like this

```
POST : user/{user-id}/message
```

This API post message on user's wall (of given user Id ).

So what is normal conventions developers following?

1. `{user-id}`, should be only the one in session OR
2. `{user-id}`, can be anything. If this is the case then any user would be able to post on any other user by just giving different user-id.

Comment: You should read something about token based authentications. If this is implemented later you can add that token to your post request and only if this is valid your web server will process that post.

Comment: I read token based authentication . It allow user to login give him acess taken which is return in every request. Fine but how do I know If current login user allow to post on some other users Post or not ? Because as per above API .. just give userId and you can post a message. Any suggestion on workflow

Comment: You have his token? So check if this token is assigned to an user with security clearance to add that post.